# using a keystore with RUN@cloud

Tags: java, encryption, cloudbees

We reference a keystore in our app that is store on the app server's file system. Any way to upload that to CloudBees and reference it during deployment?

Comment: Well, a JKS keystore is just a file which you can load using the `KeyStore.load` command. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload a file separated from your deployment unit (war archive in most cases), so a common practice is to put the keystore in META-INF inside the war. Other option is for you to create a [clickstack](https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStack) plugin, that handle this keystore.